# Win32 messages for multi-window mode operations in Windows 8

Tags: winapi, windows-8, multi-window

Are there any WM_* messages for multi-window mode operations such as resizing or swapping? In a Win32 application I need to differentiate between normal/traditional resizing of application window & resizing due to multi-window operations such as window swap.

Comment: No, Microsoft decided in their infinite wisdom that you don't need to know such things. You can't even trigger snap programatically.

Comment: I think MS would say that, no, you don't need to differentiate. It might help us if you explained what you were planning to use the information for.